# Execution of an external program in MATLAB - succeeds only when using &(ampersand), but then does not wait for completion

Tags: matlab, system, command-prompt

I am attempting to execute an external program from Matlab:

```
cmdstr = sprintf('"%s\\myEXECUTABLE" "%s" -options',fullEXEpath, fullInputFilePath);
[status, res] = system(cmdstr);
```

I receive "status = 1", partial program output in "res" (though no error message) and no output files.

BUT, executing exactly the same command with & (ampersand):

```
cmdstr = sprintf('"%s\\myEXECUTABLE" "%s" -options &',fullEXEpath, fullInputFilePath);
[status, res] = system(cmdstr);
```

Meaning in the background via a dos command window, works just fine (status equals 0 and output files are created).

I have seen somewhere it might be that the antivirus is blocking the program from executing via Matlab, but I cannot disable it since I am an endpoint user.

Using "**&**" causes my GUI to open a command window and run in the background, while immediately resuming Matlab code.

I can live with the command window opening, but not with Matlab resuming right away, as I use the output files in my MATLAB code, which are not necessarily ready.

Is there a way to verify the external program has ended?
I tried simply:

```
while (status)  %waiting for system to return status = 0
    disp 'waiting...';
end
```

but it seems to still return with "status = 0" before completion...

Or rather - is there a way to avoid the &?

Any answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

as a debugging method, you can use
    system(cmdstr,'-echo')

Since the error messages have nowhere to go, you wouldn't see them. (matlab only returns the output, which might not contain the error stream)

Am I correct you are calling a GUI program with that command? According to the matlab documentation:

> The ampersand, &, character has special meaning. For console programs
>   this causes the console to open. Omitting this character causes
>   console programs to run iconically. For GUI programs, appending this
>   character causes the application to run in the background. MATLAB
>   continues processing.

So console programs (headless programs) would not allow Matlab to continue while executing.